# Apache Spark SQL(DataSet) convert to DataFrame (for kmeans)

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to translate the data I read from sql to `DataFrame` format. How can I do it?

```
Dataset<Row> ds = sparkSession.read().jdbc(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kkj", "gghh", jj);
ds.createOrReplaceTempView("data");
sparkSession.sql("select * from data").show();
```

Comment: DataFrame is basically Dataset<Row>.  sparkSession.read().jdbc() returns a DataFrame. You can check the Sourcecode here. https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).